# Android 4.0 detect if the user has hardware back/home keys

Tags: android

Is there a way in ICS / HC to detect if the user has access to a hardware menu key?

Depending on the configuration I'm hoping to change how the actionbar is populated, e.g:

If the user has a physical home button, reduce the number of buttons shown in the actionbar.

Thanks,
Laurence

Comment: Why do you have those in the action bar at all?  They're already in the system bar.

Comment: An example would be the search key, if the user has the search key I don't want to show it in the actionbar.

Comment: You're probably better off changing things based on the [phone's model.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL)

Answer (score 2):

Took me some time but I've found a more reliable way than relying on **hasPermanentMenuKey()** which doesn't work for newer phones like the **HTC One** which have no menu key but do have home & back keys so don't need (or show) the soft navigation bar.  To get around this try the following code which checks for a back button too:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

if(!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {
    // Do whatever you need to do, this device has a navigation bar
}
```

Comment: Nexus 6 with no hardware keys, still returns true on KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

Answer (score 0):

both ICS and honeycomb (sadly) replaced the menu key for combination of the action bar and system bar ,without letting us to configure when we wish to show a menu button.

just don't assume that it exists , or set the target sdk to be 10 which will always show a menu key (which looks like 3 dots) .

anyway , it would be interesting if you find a way to check if the menu button exists.